# Tensorflow: how to view checkpoint in tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

Suppose I have checkpoint with content:

```
checkpoint
├── model.ckpt-240000.data-00000-of-00001
├── model.ckpt-240000.index
└── model.ckpt-240000.meta
```

Is it possible to view content of checkpoint in tensorboard or it only possible converting to `.pb` format?

Comment: AFAIK TensorBoard reads summaries, not the actual checkpoints.

Comment: @E_net4 It also can show a graph.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like it can be done like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default() as g:
    tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoint/model.ckpt-240000.meta')

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes', graph=g)
```

And then `tensorboard --logdir checkpoint_log_dir/faceboxes/`